# PartiQL query with DynamoDB error: "Must have at least one non-optional hash key condition in WHERE clause when using ORDER BY clause."

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, partiql

"Logs" table in DynamoDB has a simple partition key:

[image: Partition key]

It also has a global secondary index:

[image: Global secondary index]

My query statement is:

```
SELECT *
FROM "Logs"."CustomerIdentifier-Timestamp-index"
WHERE "CustomerIdentifier" = 'ABC123'
AND "Timestamp" >= 638014484314658930
AND "Timestamp" <= 638014484914658930
ORDER BY "Timestamp"
```

And the error message returned from Dynamo is "Must have at least one non-optional hash key condition in WHERE clause when using ORDER BY clause."

I would have thought that `WHERE "CustomerIdentifier" = 'ABC123'` meets this requirement. I am assuming that `Timestamp` being a range is problem, but I really don't understand why. Can someone explain a) what have I done wrong here? b) conceptually, is this type of query possible in Dynamo? and c) if so, how would I accomplish it?

Comment: If either of the lines beginning with `AND "Timestamp"` is commented out, the query runs. But I am still unsure why this is the case.